# i have a problem with flexbox and i need a solution

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css

I put two divs next to each other, instead of them having **100vw** each, the two are **dividing 50% of the space for each one**, is there any solution? Thanks.

[Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Ou7.png)

```js
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";

import "./global.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <div className="w-screen h-screen bg-red-400">mobile menu</div>
      <div className="w-screen h-screen bg-blue-400">
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `flex-none` to childs of `div` with class `flex`.

```
.......
 <div className="flex">
    <div className="w-screen h-screen bg-red-400 flex-none">mobile menu</div>
    <div className="w-screen h-screen bg-blue-400 flex-none">
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </div>
</div>
........
```

Comment: I need both to be side by side, and both to have 100vw

Comment: @WeslleyDev just add `flex-none`

Comment: same result ... :c